# angularjs adding custom validation for date to check if weekday is in a range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Hello I want to add a custom validator to a date input the right way.

I use for default validation this structure:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="appointmentForm.firstName" ng-minlength=2 required>
</div>
<div role="alert">
  <span class="error" ng-if="submitted && form.firstName.$error.minlength" >
    Vul een geldige voornaam
  </span>
</div>
...
```

So I'm searching a way that I can validate if a weekday of an input type date is in the range of Tuesday to Sunday like this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" ng-model="appointmentForm.date" validate-weekday>
```

How do I implement the custom validator on angular side?

Comment: check out MomentJS :) it will certainly help you

Comment: Although not exactly the same context, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29775049/1526037) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most certainly on the correct path by starting off with a directive. 
All the directive will do is to attach a validation handler to the validator collection with your logic

I have created a stub code which you may use to kick start the process. You will have to modify the actual validation code to represent your business logic

```
app.directive('validateWeekday', [function () {

    function validate(value) {
        //replace me with correct logic
        return value == 'this is valid';
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.invalidWeekday = function (modelValue) {
                return validate(modelValue);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

And the html would be something like

```
<form name="appointmentForm">
    <input type="text" name="dateOfPurchase" ng-model="dateOfPurchase" validate-weekday>
    <div class="error-message" ng-show="appointmentForm.dateOfPurchase.$error.invalidWeekday">Valid date is required.</div>
</form>
```

Also have a look at ngMesages and other validation goodies in angular 1.3, to make your code more elegant

Comment: Yes this looks exactly for what I was looking for.

But what are the correct return values in the validate function? I didn't understand why you checking the value if its 'this is valid'.

Comment: What I have given you is just a stub code. You will have to put your logic to do the validation to `validate` function. I assume you will have all the valid dates in an array and check the passed in date against the values in the array.